# Why are images not added to the local registry during build? [Podman-in-Podman]

Tags: dockerfile, containers, podman

I have the following (example) Containerfile:

```
FROM quay.io/podman/stable

RUN podman pull hello-world
RUN podman images
```

If I inspect the output from `podman build -t test-1 .`, I see that the `hello-world` image is not added to the local registry. In contrast, if I squash all the layers (`podman build -t test-1 . --squash`), the image is available in the local registry, but not when I perform `podman run --privileged -it --rm test-1 podman images`.

Why are images not stored during the build?